# Remove FirePHP headers with Varnish

Tags: http-headers, varnish, firephp, chromephp

I've got a line in my Varnish default.vcl that successfully clears the ChromePHP headers:

```
sub vcl_fetch {
    remove beresp.http.X-ChromeLogger-Data;
}
```

I'm trying to do the same thing for FirePHP, but the data for FirePHP is spread out over many headers rather than all in one:

- X-Wf-Protocol-1
- X-Wf-1-Plugin-1
- X-Wf-1-1-1-9
- X-Wf-1-1-1-43
- etc

How can I tell Varnish to remove any headers that start with "X-Wf-"? I can't find any documentation that includes a wildcard for the header name.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, remove the `x-wf-*` request headers which will cause the response headers not to be issued. You can hardcode the names of the few request headers.